# The Jeweler and the Five Rings

Tags: mathematics

A king asks a learned man to visit his palace, to which the learned man responds:

"I will come some day next month, but I will not tell you on which day. Further, you must give me gold in grams equal to the date on which I come."

In preparation for the visit, the king demands that his jeweler make gold rings of 1 to 31 grams.

The wise jeweler made only 5 rings. What are their weights?

Answer (score 12):

the weights of 5 rings are:

> 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 grams

Using these combination of 5 type of weights you can reward 1-31 grams in weight to the wise man.

Example:

> If wise man visit on 3rd day, you can give him ring with 1 & 2 grams.
>
>  If wise man visit on 15th day, you can give him ring with 1, 2, 4, 8 grams.
>
>  If wise man visit on 30th day, you can give him ring with 2, 4, 8, 16 grams.

You can do this for all possible number of days.

Answer (score 7):

The rings are going to weigh:

> 1, 2, 4, 8, and 16 grams
>
>  Since each ring will or will not be used, all we have to do is represent the numbers in binary, and give the corresponding rings.
>
>  As an example, 5 is 00101 in binary, so we give the rings of weight 4 and 1, and 19 will be 01011, so 16+2+1, and 31 is 11111, so we give all of the rings.