# How did the king pay the worker?

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking, strategy

> A humorous king pays his worker with one inch gold bar everyday. He had a $31$ inches gold bar and he paid the worker $31$ days of a month cutting it in just $4$ places. **How is this possible?**

Taken from the book *Neurone Abaro Onuronon* by *Muhammad Zafar Iqbal*.

Comment: Agree with @Anonymous. These are both king and gold puzzles.

Comment: But there are some differences too (4 instead of 5) @Anonymous

Comment: The solution is directly equivalent to that for [The Jeweler and the Five Rings](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/49410/the-jeweler-and-the-five-rings), just framed differently, so I have voted to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He could do it as follows

> Cut the bar of size 31 into segments of size 16|8|4|2|1
>  Clearly this can be achieved with just four cuts.
>  Then, for each day $n$, ensure the worker leaves with the gold bars which correspond to 1 in the binary representation of $n$.
>  For example, on day 21, the binary representation is 10101 so the worker must leave with the gold bars of size 16, 4 and 1.
>  This means that the worker will sometimes have to swap previous bars they've earnt. For example, on day 2, the worker will give back the gold bar of size 1 and receive the gold bar of size 2.

Comment: "Clearly this can be achieved with just four cuts" i guess that makes it 5 cuts : 
1st: 16, 2nd: 8, 3rd: 4, 4th: 2, 5th: 1

Comment: @imAProgrammer cut 1: between 16&8, cut 2: between 8&4, cut 3: between 4&2, cut 4: between 2&1.  This leaves 5 pieces from 4 cuts.

Comment: @imAProgrammer Programmers often do off-by-one errors.

Comment: @Mason what about cut between 32 & 16 ? this makes it 5 cuts

i'm sure to cut a bar of size 32 to half until you get one single element, you'll end up with 5 cuts (C.F Dichotomy)

Comment: @imAProgrammer We are cutting the bar into five pieces and that needs four cuts. In general, to cut the bar into n pieces you need n-1 cuts. For example, cutting once divides it into two pieces.